# weekday & month end identification

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

in the particular google scripting logic I have a requirement where I need to set a flag to true if the given date is a weekday or if it is a month-end.
Example:
the flag should be set to true if the date is 5/11/2020 or 5/15/2020 or 5/31/2020. However, the flag should remain false for the dates like, 5/16/2020 or 5/30/2020

Please let me know if there are any built in functions or any code snippets that I can enhance myself.

Regards
KK

Comment: `getDay()` returns values 0-6. That should be enough to  get information regarding the day. `getMonth()` and `getDate()` can be combined to get information regarding the last day (or any other day ) of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the JavaScript Date object and compare `getDay()` to 0 or 6 for weekends, in which case flag is false.

For the month end, there are many ways to do it, but I find adding a method to Date.prototype is a nice way to go about this. So you would add 1 day to the date and compare the months, flag is true if they are different.

#### Example:

```js
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}

function flagDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var flag;
  if(today.getDay()==6 || today.getDay()==0){
    // Today is weekend
    flag = false;
  } else{
    flag = true;
  }
  if(today.addDays(1).getMonth() != today.getMonth()){
    // Today is the end of the month
    flag = true;
  }
  return flag;
}
```

#### References:

- [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: I was able to incorporate your piece of code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To capture the day of the week use Date.getDay() and then check it against your requirements. Remember that 0 = Sunday, 1 Monday, etc…:

```
const someDate = isWeekday( new Date() ); // This is the date you are checking

  // if it is weekday
  if( date.getDay() != 0 || date.getDay() != 6 ){
     // do something

  } else {
    // if it is weekend, do something esle
  }
```

Alternatively you can add this to the Date.prototype.

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_getday.htm

Comment: I was able to incorporate your piece of code. Thanks for your help!